# Count how many time a string appears in a longer string

Tags: python, string

So I have a little problem,
I want to count how many times a string : `"aa"` is in my longer string `"aaatattgg"` its looks like a dna sequence.
Here for exemple I expect 2 (overlap is allow)
There is the `.count` method but overlap is not allowed
PS: excuse my english , I'm french

Comment: you can start from the first character.. and start comparing it. like in basic string matching

Answer (score 1):

Through re module. Put your regex inside positive lookarounds in-order to do overlapping match.

```
>>> import re
>>> s = "aaatattgg"
>>> re.findall(r'(?=(aa))', s)
['aa', 'aa']
>>> len(re.findall(r'(?=(aa))', s))
2
```